# How to generate native Xcode Project with specific template automatically ?( Example :Dapp - app maker)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I am trying to make new mac app, using this app we can select the rough flow of an iOS app  and we can also select the UI elements that we need in app and if we are pressing generate button , it will generate xcode project with the specific work flow that we passed in mac app.
Its my idea. Can anyone tell me the possibilty of genarating xcode project with specific template automaticcally using any tools ?

Comment: HINT: Use any Blank XCode project, browse inside `.xcodeproj`, modify project.pbxproj and project.xcworkspace, then for storyboard, add element as xml elements, same for xib. All are text files you can easily read it and modify it. Though its tough task do, lot of analysis and testing needed.

Comment: @iphonic : Is it possible to modify .pbxproj  ? Is there any way to overwrite .h and .m file programatically ?

Comment: As I said all are files, you can always write contents into it, all you need to do it create patterns of data to write for particular file. For eg. For .h file you need to write #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>\n @interface ViewController : UIViewController\n@end

Comment: I would suggest not to do these, let XCode do this, its like making an Editor, you need to do a lot of analysis.

Comment: @iphonic Lets make a try. :) But i tried to overwrite .h and .m file but Its showing commented code